# Vertical Sidebar Menu usando Bootstrap 3.3.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

O meu problema é replicar algo parecido com isto. Estou com grandes problemas para resolver isto:

http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin/

A diferença é: sem palavras. Quando faço hover sobre a barra toda, aparece o resto da width a dizer o que é cada página (no fundo o que é cada icon). ter uma poisition fixed, ou seja, quando faço o scroll a barra não anda para cima nem para baixo, mas sim sempre no mesmo sítio.

E quando estiver mobile ter um efeito de lado e não de cima para baixo.

Alguém consegue ajudar? Obrigado.

Comment: Boa noite, sua pergunta é confusa, poderia ser mais claro? Edite a pergunta e tente ser mais objetivo e descritivo, de preferencia mantendo a organização do texto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poderes ter uma navegação lateral onde só aparecem os icons e com rato por cima aparecem os icons e a legenda, precisas de um pouco de CSS para formatação e JavaScript para controlar se o rato está ou não por cima do menu de forma a apresentar as legendas.

**CSS**

A formatação, naturalmente, depende do layout da tua navegação, mas a parte importante é que o elemento que contém a legenda esteja escondido por defeito:

```css
#sideBar > ul > li > a > span {
    display:none;
}
```

<sup>Saber mais sobre a propriedade [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).</sup>

**JavaScript**

O segredo efetivamente está no código em baixo, que com recurso a jQuery simplificamos o processo de apurar se o rato está ou não em cima do menu:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sideBar')
        .mouseenter(function () {
            $("a > span", this).show(); // rato entrou no menu, apresentar legenda
        })
        .mouseleave(function () {
            $("a > span", this).hide(); // rato saiu do menu, esconder legenda
        });
});
```

<sup>Saber mais sobre os métodos [`mouseenter`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) e [`mouseleave`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/).</sup>

## Exemplo

Exemplo também no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/gdfmr198/).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sideBar')
        .mouseenter(function () {
            $("a > span", this).show();
        })
        .mouseleave(function () {
            $("a > span", this).hide();
        });
});
```

```css
#sideBar{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:#222;
    padding:0 10px;
}
#sideBar > ul {
    float:left;
}
#sideBar > ul > li > a{
    color:#9d9d9d;
}
#sideBar > ul > li > a:hover{
    background:#080808;
    color:#FFF;
}
#sideBar > ul > li > a > span {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="sideBar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
        <li class="active"> <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="charts.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart-o"></i> <span>Charts</span></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="tables.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-table"></i> <span>Tables</span></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="forms.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i> <span>Forms</span></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="bootstrap-elements.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-desktop"></i> <span>Bootstrap Elements</span></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="bootstrap-grid.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-wrench"></i> <span>Bootstrap Grid</span></a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="blank-page.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-file"></i> <span>Blank Page</span></a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

## Sem JavaScript

Podes também atingir o mesmo comportamento apenas com CSS. Ver exemplo neste [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/cbsja87q/) onde foi removido o CSS e adicionado a *pseudo-class* de CSS [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) para o menu:

```css
#sideBar:hover > ul > li > a > span {
    display:inline-block;
}
```